# Special Scenario : java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;

Tags: java, arrays, object, arraylist, casting

I am simply trying to remove below exception.
**java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;**
Please help me out here.

I need to cast it as List<String[]>. How should i handle it?

```
  List<Object[]> values =  query.getResultList();
    List<String[]> strings = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Object[] object : values) {
        strings.add((String[]) object);
    }
```

> values : = [obj1,obj2,obj3]
>
> obj1 = "1", "01";
> obj2 = "1", "02";
> obj3 = "1:, "03";

Comment: Have you tried casting each element of the object array? I mean a deeper casting.

Comment: yes. This is ultimately i need which is not happening. gave same exception
..... 
Map<String, List<String>> resultMap = values.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy
        (o -> (o)[0].toString(), Collectors.mapping(o -> (o)[1].toString(), Collectors.toList())));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me finally

```
values.forEach(o->{ strings.add(Arrays.copyOf(o, o.length, String[].class));});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the System.arraycopy

```
package com.lsk.backend;


import java.util.*;
import java.util.List;


/**
 * @ClassName : Test  //className
 * @Description :   //description
 * @Author : shikai.liu  //author
 * @Date: 2020-08-27 09:13  //Date
 */
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Object[]> values =  getResultList();
        List<String[]> strings = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Object[] object : values) {
            String[]dst=new String[object.length];
            System.arraycopy(object,0,dst,0,dst.length);
            strings.add(dst);
        }
        System.out.println(strings);
    }
    public static List<Object[]>getResultList(){
        Object[][]result={
                {
                    "0","1"
                },
                {
                        "0","2"
                },
                {
                        "0","3"
                },
        };
        List<Object[]>ss=Arrays.asList(result);
        return ss;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Object[]> values =  query.getResultList();
List<String[]> strings = new ArrayList<>();
values.forEach(object -> {
   String [] stringArray = new String[object.length];
   System.arraycopy(object, 0, stringArray, 0,object.length);
   strings.add(stringArray);
});
```